# get a certain request url during Loading a web page

Tags: python, qt, browser, web-scraping, scrapy

During Loading [this web page](http://www.le.com/ptv/vplay/1417484.html) , the browser makes many requests, 
[image]
now I need a certain request url (e.g.starts with `'http://api.le.com/mms/out/video/playJson?'`) during the Loading process ,and the request is made on condition that the adobe flash player plugin for NPAPI is enabled , so any way to get the url?

P.S. Better to show some code, I am new to this area.

Comment: Could you provide some concrete examples of what you are looking for and url of the page?

Comment: @Granitosaurus see the updated post

Comment: why do you want to replicate the request there? You can most likely replicate this behaviour by chaining few requests, i.e. connect to page -> find some data in source -> use that data for second connection -> profit.

Comment: @Granitosaurus in the step -> find some data in source -> , the data needed to  replicate the request url has been encrypted , so I resort for help to some browser like tools to get the direct url rather than figure out the encryption algorithm of the data within the url.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy doesn't handle requests while the page is being processed, you either know specifically the url you want and directly request it

or

You have to use something like [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) which can return a `HAR` file with all the requests made while loading the page. The only downside to this is that splash doesn't return the contents of each request, only the headers =(

If you absolutely need the contents of the request it's best to use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) with [browsermob](https://github.com/AutomatedTester/browsermob-proxy-py), if you find a better solution please do tell.

**EDIT**

Seems now that Splash does handle requests' body, check @Mikhail comment.

Comment: I have tried Qt WebEngine to attack the issue here , but also encountered some problems https://forum.qt.io/topic/69982/wrap-qapplication-exec-into-a-function-or-class/12

Comment: I'm not familiar with pyQT, sorry

Comment: Splash 2.2 can now return content of requests; see http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-response-body-enabled, http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-request-object.html#splash-request-enable-response-body and http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#arg-response-body

Comment: @MikhailKorobov Thank you for that info, updated my answer